# {TypeError}unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow to build a model and want to train it, but I get this error:

> {TypeError}unhashable type: `'numpy.ndarray'`

one part of my code as follows:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(a.epochs):
        input, target = load_batch_data(batch_size=16, a=a)
        batch_input = input.astype(np.float32)
        batch_target = target.astype(np.float32)
        sess.run(predict_real, feed_dict={input: batch_input, target: batch_target})
```

`'predict_real'` is the output of my model, I just try to run it, but error!

here is the code of my model:

```
def build_model(input, target):
    with tf.variable_scope("generator"):
      out_channels = int(target.get_shape()[-1])
      outputs = create_generator(input, out_channels)


    with tf.name_scope("real_discriminator"):
        with tf.variable_scope("discriminator"):
           predict_real = create_discriminator(input, target)

    with tf.name_scope("fake_discriminator"):
         with tf.variable_scope("discriminator", reuse=True):
           predict_fake = create_discriminator(input, outputs)

    with tf.name_scope("discriminator_loss"):
         discrim_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-(tf.log(predict_real + EPS) + tf.log(1 - predict_fake + EPS)))

    with tf.name_scope("generator_loss"):
       gen_loss_GAN = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(predict_fake + EPS))
       gen_loss_L1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - outputs))
       gen_loss = gen_loss_GAN * a.gan_weight + gen_loss_L1 * a.l1_weight

    with tf.name_scope("discriminator_train"):
       discrim_tvars = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if var.name.startswith("discriminator")]
       discrim_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(a.lr, a.beta1)
       discrim_grads_and_vars = discrim_optim.compute_gradients(discrim_loss, var_list=discrim_tvars)
       discrim_train = discrim_optim.apply_gradients(discrim_grads_and_vars)

    with tf.name_scope("generator_train"):
        with tf.control_dependencies([discrim_train]):
            gen_tvars = [var for var in tf.trainable_variables() if var.name.startswith("generator")]
            gen_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(a.lr, a.beta1)
            gen_grads_and_vars = gen_optim.compute_gradients(gen_loss, var_list=gen_tvars)
            gen_train = gen_optim.apply_gradients(gen_grads_and_vars)

    ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(decay=0.99)
    update_losses = ema.apply([discrim_loss, gen_loss_GAN, gen_loss_L1])

    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    incr_global_step = tf.assign(global_step, global_step+1)
    return Model(
      predict_real=predict_real,
      predict_fake=predict_fake,
      discrim_loss=ema.average(discrim_loss),
      discrim_grads_and_vars=discrim_grads_and_vars,
      gen_loss_GAN=ema.average(gen_loss_GAN),
      gen_loss_L1=ema.average(gen_loss_L1),
      gen_grads_and_vars=gen_grads_and_vars,
      outputs=outputs,
      train=tf.group(update_losses, incr_global_step, gen_train),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

From python documentation:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be
>   compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() method). Hashable
>   objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
>   member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no
>   mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which
>   are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they
>   all compare unequal, and their hash value is their id().

(https://docs.python.org/3.1/glossary.html)

You are trying to create a dict from ndarray, which is not hashable.

You can try to use `tuple(np.ndarray)`

P.S. Please, make your question easier to understand. Posting your entire code is not a good way to get an answer.  You should debug and find the exact line where the problem is, print the input, the output and say what you expected instead of what you got.

Comment: It isn't easy to understand from the question or answer where this error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem as I was trying to feed a dictionary in the wrong way